# Non-point lights

Tags: shader, glsl, lighting

Is there a technique for implementing non-point lights (i.e. light that has actual physical dimensions)?

I can't think of anything except than making a light source out of multiple point lights, but that doesn't seem feasible for real-time rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are other physically based lighting concepts. You can have a look at image based lighting and Area Lights (such as Sphere or Tube lights).

If you have access, have look into [Physically Based Rendering](http://www.pbrt.org/), if i recall correctly, that has a chapter or two about non-point lights.
Free on the internet is for example [Real Shading in Unreal Engine 4](https://cdn2.unrealengine.com/Resources/files/2013SiggraphPresentationsNotes-26915738.pdf). Furthermore, there is the [Physically Based Lighting at Pixar](https://graphics.pixar.com/library/PhysicallyBasedLighting/paper.pdf) paper, although I am not sure how real-time suitable this is.

This should give you a starting point into the topic. You should read up on it and then perhaps come back, if you have more detailed questions.